# extracting data from plot with specific step

Tags: plotting, data

I use this code to extracting data as two-column in a txt file (Data1.txt). The problem is the points are extracted in a random step. And this step changes every time I run the code. How can I modify it so that the extracted data has a fixed step, say 0.05.

````
Fig1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]

Data1 = Flatten[Cases[Fig1, Line[x__] -> x, Infinity], 1];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "Data1.txt", Data1, "CSV"];
```
````

Comment: MMA uses an adaptive algorithm to sample dense where the function changes a lot and sample less dense where the function changes  little. Therefore, I think it is better to get equally spaced data points using e.g. a `Table` command instead of digging them out of the plot.

Comment: @DanielHuber How can I use "Table" in my case?

Comment: `Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi,0.05}]`   or  `Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 6 Pi,0.05}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber That's what I want. thank you very much.

Comment: If the function is computationally expensive and the plot has already been generated, you could use `Data1 = Module[{f = Interpolation[ Flatten[Cases[Fig1, Line[x__] -> x, Infinity], 1]]}, {#, f[#]} & /@ Range[0, 6 Pi, 0.05]];`